# Scan a string and right after print something

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using nextLine() to scan the string and length() to find the length,right after I need to print it's length.

In the console,when I enter the string hello world ,the output need to be like this:

```
Enter a string:
hello world 11
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code boi

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible because the String will only be read after the user hit [Enter] So you can either print the length in the next line or output it all together after the input

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm not sure if I misunderstood you but i think this should work:

```
System.out.print(yourString.length());
```